# Oracle 12.2 Dynamically Partition an unpartitioned table

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I inherited an Oracle DB where the tables and their indexes have become impossibly large.  I'm trying to dynamically partition the table by range (every 30 days).  I've done the following:

```
alter table <TABLE> modify
partition by range (<DATE>) interval (numtodsinterval(30, 'day'))
(partition <TABLE>_PART values less than (date'2020-01-01')
)
update indexes
(<TABLE>_<DATE>_IDX1 local,
<TABLE>_IDX1 global partition by range (<DATE>)
(partition IP1 values less than (maxvalue))
);
```

I'm getting the error "ORA-14427: table does not support modification to a partitioned state DDL"

I checked that

1. The TABLE is not partitioned (did a select partitioned,
   dba_tables.* from dba_tables where table_name = 'TABLE')
2. The  does not have a view or materialized view dependencies
3. I did find (using all_dependencies) that there are hard dependencies due
   to some attributes being an array or geometry type

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: Your syntax works for me on a simple test table.  Maybe you should post your full DDL here and we can try to find the problem.  Generate the code with: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME') from dual;`

Comment: Do you really like `INTERVAL  30 DAY`? Maybe `INTERVAL '1' MONTH` would be better.

Comment: This part `<TABLE>_IDX1 global partition by range (<DATE>)
(partition IP1 values less than (maxvalue))` look strange to me. Do you really like to create a Global Partitioned Index - they are very uncommon.Usually you create **Local** indexes or **Global Nonpartitioned** indexes.

Comment: Does your organisation have an Oracle Support account? If so you should check out [ORA-14427 While Trying To Alter partition table contains SDO_GEOMETRY column (Doc ID 2581497.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2581497_1.html)

Comment: When you use `partition ... values less than (date '2020-01-01')` then you create one "impossibly large" partition (for existing data) and only future data will be split in monthly partitions. Is this your intention?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no that is not my intention.  I want to create a partition for every month before the NY.  The data in this table is at least 5 years worth of data with over 70,000 records added a day!.

Comment: Then you should run `values less than (date '2010-01-01')`. NB, for empty years Oracle will not create partitions, only the initial one for `2010-01-01` will be created in any case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is there a way to add a loop so that it will create a partition for every month?

Comment: You can create a loop of `ATLER TABLE ... SPLIT PARTITION`, however give an initial date which is lower than smallest date in your table should perform the same action by a single command (but I dit not test it).